# Join from table to table in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

What kind of relation should I have to get from `Property` model:

- the `name` field from `default_characteristics`
- the `value` field from `characteristic_value`

How can I do this? Can I do it with one relation?

Before adding `characteristic_value` table, on `value_id` from property_characteristics I had only string `value` field, and all was working with.

```
  public function characteristics() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(
        'Proactiv\DefaultCharacteristic',
        'property_characteristics',
        'property_id',
        'characteristic_id')
        ->withPivot('value');
 } // In Property model.
```

This is the RAW SQL that returns correct data:

```
SELECT a.name, c.name, d.value FROM properties a

INNER JOIN property_characteristics b

on a.id = b.property_id

INNER JOIN default_characteristics C

on b.characteristic_id = c.id

INNER JOIN characteristic_values d

on b.value_id = d.id

WHERE a.id = 1

AND c.name = 'rooms'
```

Returns: Property Name, rooms, 3

[image]

Comment: Do you want to built query ? or what do you mean  of "do this with one relation" ?

Comment: I want to use Laravel Eloquent relations to achieve.

Comment: I think You must make another relation in PropertyCharacteristic Model with CharacteristicValue Model :
 $this->belongsTo(Proactiv\CharacteristicValue', 'value_id');

Comment: I already did that but how do I call? I am blocked here: `$this->characteristics
                    ->where('name', 'rooms')
                    ->first()->.............` where `$this` is the `Property` model.

Answer (score 0):

I think The best choice for you using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins) 
Or You can Try this :

```
$property = new Property();
$property->with("DefaultCharacteristic.PropertyCharacteristic.CharacteristicValue")->where(...)->first();
```